# Grant a Keycloak client service account permissions to create realm users without using the broad manage-users role

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, redhat-sso

I have a web application that is leveraging Keycloak for IdM.

I am using the  [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#flows) or Direct Grant flow for authentication which uses REST API calls to `/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token` instead of browser redirects to get the user a JWT.

I would like to implement a similar workflow for signing users up.

Looking at the Keycloak documentation it appears the Keycloak Admin API exposes an endpoint for this at [/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource).

To allow clients to interact with the Keycloak Admin API you have to create a [client service account](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/index.html#_service_accounts) and associate it with a keycloak role with sufficient privilege to manage realm users.

The expected approach for this seems to be to apply the [manage-users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#realm-specific-roles) realm specific role to the client service account. This is more permissions than I would like to grant to the client.

Is there a way to grant a client service account *just* the ability to create new users and not the full set of permissions that comes with manage-users?

Comment: Ok it doesn't help .. but I encounter similar issues with other flows and use cases. I could not find a way to limit the roles all coming with 'manage-users'. I think its a broader issue and they (at Keycloak community) might be aware of ti. Check out their JIRA.

Comment: Same here. I have a similar use case for only creating a client, but without manage-clients role, the user cannot create a new client. There's a role, create-client in realm-management, I try that one but the user still cannot create a new client. Not sure what that role is doing....

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems that you cannot edit the `manage-users` role or create a new one with more fine grain control from the console. Looking at the source code you will probably have to fork the repo and add your expected behavior.

The way seems to be to create a new variable in the `AdminRoles.java` file like:

```
public static String CREATE_USERS = "create-users";
```

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/d9b271c22a170e003f328873a6a05a2665e7f79b/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/AdminRoles.java#L46

Then use it only in the places where the `MANAGER_USERS` enum is used for the users creation in the source code, it seems to be under the `UserPermissions.java`, `RolePermissions.java`, `GroupPermissions.java` and `RealmAuth.java` files.

Then build your custom keycloak distribution following the official guideline:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak#building-from-source